# Install Vuetify 3 with Vue CLI 5.x

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3, vue-cli-5

In vuetify documention:

> The current version of Vuetify does not support Vue 3. Support for Vue
> 3 will come with the release of Vuetify v3. When creating a new
> project, please ensure you selected Vue 2 from the Vue CLI prompts, or
> that you are installing to an existing Vue 2 project.

Can i use vuetify 3 with Vue CLI 5 (Vue 3)? I installed them but get errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you may have missed a step to define which version.

if you run `vue add vuetify` and select Vuetify 3, you should be able to install it

[image]

it also works with `Vuetify3 + Vite` setup

[image]

Comment: Thanks. i installed vutify 3 Preview (viutify 3). but that is nightly version and is not good for production version.